# How does the c++ sizeof operator calculate size?

Tags: c++, class, sizeof

I created a class X having only 2 public functions (constructor and destructor), and using `sizeof` operator the class size is coming to be 1.

When I add a private data member of type `char` to the above class declaration, the size is still 1.
Finally I add an integer type to it as a class data member, and now the size is 8 bytes.

Kindly explain to me the how a class size is calculated.

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, realise that functions that are not virtual have no effect on the size of a class.

The size of an instance of *any* class is at least 1 byte, even if the class is empty, so that different objects will have different addresses.

Adding a `char` ensures that different objects will have different addresses, so the compiler doesn't artificially add one to the size. The size is then `sizeof(char)` = 1.

Then you add an `int`, which (probably) adds 4 bytes on your platform. The compiler then decides to pad the class so it will be aligned for performance/CPU-requirements reasons, and adds 3 empty bytes so that the size is now 1 + 3 + 4 = 8. It probably adds the padding before the `int` member so that it will be aligned on a 4 byte boundary, but it's not required to unless your CPU requires it.

You can read about padding on [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Comment: I would expect it to be `c---iiii` rather than `ciiii---`, as this answer implies.

Comment: @zch I didn't mean to imply that since it's up to the compiler. But I will change the order of the addition and add a note if it makes it seem less confusing.

Comment: thanks a lot @SethCarnegie for the explanation.I know a little bit about padding, will dig deeper into it as I have a doubt that why there is no padding when only one char is declared even when the boundary is 4 bytes. :)

Comment: @user2100866 Compilers will usually try to align the structs to be a multiple of the size of the largest member. So when you have just a char, the largest member is 1, so the size is unaltered. For int, the it's 4, so the size is a multiple of 4. That's why it doesn't pad it when it's just a char.

Answer (score 8):

There are many factors that decide the size of an object of a class in C++. These factors are:

1. Size of all non-static data members
2. Order of data members
3. Byte alignment or byte padding
4. Size of its immediate base class
5. The existence of virtual function(s) (Dynamic polymorphism using virtual functions).
6. Compiler being used
7. Mode of inheritance (virtual inheritance)

You can find more here http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/size_of_class_object.html